# Get field value in apex:repeat row, when checkbox is selected

Tags: visualforce, javascript, datatable

I'm trying to populate an amount field at the top of a table when a row's checkbox is selected, this is only for UI purposes and does not need to be written to the DB.

The checkbox itself is a field on a record, so using $(this).val to get its value doesn't work. There is another field on the row, which is called Total_Including_GST__c, this is the field that i need to sum.

How would I write the JS to grab the fields value?

VF:

```
<input class="form-control" style="height:42px;" disabled="disabled" id="price" type="number" name="amount" placeholder="Selected Amount"/>

<table id="invoicesTable" class="table table-striped" style="width:100%;">
    <thead class="tableHeadBlue">
    <tr>
        <td>Invoice Number</td>
        <td>Invoice Date</td>
        <td>Invoice Amount</td>
        <td>Remittance Amount</td>
        <td>Remittance #</td>
        <td>Balance</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">Reconciles? &nbsp;&nbsp;<apex:inputCheckbox style="font-size:30px;" styleClass="check" onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId1')"/></td>
        <td align="right" style="width:120px;">Action</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <apex:repeat value="{!getInvoicesOut}" var="invOut">
        <tr>
            <td><apex:outputField styleClass="form-control" value="{!invOut.OrderNumber}"/></td>
            <td><apex:outputField styleClass="form-control" value="{!invOut.EffectiveDate}"/></td>
            <td><apex:outputField id="totalAmount" styleClass="form-control total" value="{!invOut.Total_Including_GST__c}"/></td>
            <td><apex:inputField styleClass="form-control" value="{!invOut.Payment_Received__c}" html-placeholder="$0.00"/></td>
            <td><apex:inputField styleClass="form-control" value="{!invOut.Payment_Received_Number__c}" html-Placeholder="Remittance #"/></td>
            <td><apex:outputField styleClass="form-control" value="{!invOut.Balance_Calculated__c}"/></td>
            <td>
                <label class="formCheck">
                    <apex:inputCheckbox id="inputId1" styleClass="check" style="font-size:24px;" onchange="selectedCheckbox();" value="{!invOut.Remittance_Reconciles__c}"/>
                    <!--<input type="checkbox" id="inputId2" class="check" style="font-size:24px;" value="{!invOut.Total_Including_GST__c}"/>-->
                </label>
            </td>
            <td><apex:outputlink style="text-decoration:none;" styleClass="pull-right" target="__blank" value="/{!invOut.id}">View Invoice</apex:outputlink></td>
        </tr>
    </apex:repeat>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS:

```
$('input[class="check"]').change(function(){
    var totalprice = 0;

    $('input[class="check"]:checked').each(function(){
        totalprice = totalprice + parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    $('#price').val(totalprice);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the both answers, I have solved the issue by utilising JQuery and JS...

```
function updateTotals() {
    var sum = Array.prototype.reduce.call(document.querySelectorAll("input.check:checked"),(a,v) => a + parseFloat(v.dataset.totalIncludingGst), 0);
    $('#price').val(sum);
};
```

and the field markup:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox 
    styleClass="check" 
    style="font-size:24px;" 
    html-data-total-including-gst="{!invOut.Total_Including_GST__c}"
    onchange="updateTotals();" 
    value="{!invOut.Remittance_Reconciles__c}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the field is read-only, I'd suggest you just move the data to the checkbox itself:

```
<apex:inputCheckbox 
    styleClass="check" 
    style="font-size:24px;" 
    html-data-total-including-gst="{!invOut.Total_Including_GST__c}"
    onchange="updateTotals();" 
    value="{!invOut.Remittance_Reconciles__c}"/>
```

Which you can get in your method:

```
function updateTotals() {
  var sum = Array.prototype.reduce.call(document.querySelectorAll("input.check:checked"),
    (a,v) => a + parseFloat(v.dataset.totalIncludingGst), 0);
  document.querySelector("#price").innerText = "$"+sum;
}
```

---

## Self-Contained Example

### Controller

```
public class q214935 {
    public Decimal[] values { get; set; }
    public q214935() {
        values = new Decimal[] { 1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6 };
    }
}
```

### Page

```
<apex:page controller="q214935">
    <input disabled="disabled" id="price" />
    <script>
    function updateTotals() {
        var sum = Array.prototype.reduce.call(document.querySelectorAll("input.check:checked"),
            (a,v) => a + parseFloat(v.dataset.totalIncludingGst), 0);
        document.querySelector("#price").value = "$"+sum;
    }
    </script>
    <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!values}" var="value">
            <apex:column>
                <apex:inputCheckbox styleClass="check"
                                    onchange="updateTotals()"
                                    html-data-total-including-gst="{!value}" />
            </apex:column>
            <apex:column>
                {!value}
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Hey sfdcfox, thanks for the response. Using your suggestion, there is no result. I tried with a standard input checkbox to see if it was the html pass through, still no luck...

Comment: @TheMikeyBoosh You've done something else wrong, then, because I wrote up a mockup in my org and copied the function verbatim, and it works. I've included my mockup in the answer for you to take a look at/play with.

Comment: You have the price writing to a div, however I am trying to write to a disabled input field. I have tried the DIV and that works (albeit with Nan value)

Comment: (Ignore NaN, my error!)

Comment: @TheMikeyBoosh You'd set the value attribute instead, then. I've updated the example to reflect this. If all you're doing is some basic manipulation like this, I'd recommend ditching jQuery; it's simply not necessary.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid using pageblocks or any other standard vf components? as the page has other functionality which i am trying to maintain. Ideally I would like to keep my original example's syntax.

Comment: I have replaced your last line "document.querySelector("#price").value = "$"+sum;" with "$('#price').val(sum);" and it works. Is there a reason you wouldn't have gone down this path?

Comment: @TheMikeyBoosh Yes, you could use normal HTML; my example is meant to be a complete self-contained example without the need for external libraries. As a general rule, I don't use jQuery unless I need complicated DOM manipulation, because the cost of loading jQuery is often not worth it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [.closest()](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/) function of jQuery to get the price from the `<apex:outputText` correcesponding selected `<apex:inputCheckbox`.

The `.closest()` function defined as "*For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.*"

Please find this below example, the value of `<input id="totalprice" />` gets updated when the user selects/deselects any checkbox.

VF Page

```
<apex:page controller="repeatCon" id="thePage">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <input id="totalprice" />
    <hr/>
    <apex:form>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>Select</td>
            </tr>
            <apex:repeat value="{!decimals}" var="decval" id="theRepeat">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <apex:outputText id="gstprice" value="{!decval}"/><br/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <apex:inputCheckbox id="calcprice"/>
                    </td>
                </tr> 
            </apex:repeat> 
        </table>
    </apex:form>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var j$ = jQuery.noConflict(); 
        j$('input[id*=calcprice]').change(function() {
            var totPrice = 0;
            j$('input[id*=calcprice]:checked').each(function(){
                totPrice = totPrice + parseFloat(j$(this).closest('tr').find('span[id*=price]').text());
             });
            console.log(totPrice);
            j$('#totalprice').val(totPrice);
        });    
    </script>                        
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class repeatCon {
    public Decimal[] getDecimals() {
        return new Decimal[]{1.2, 2.3, 3.4, 4.5, 5.6};
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Saroj, thanks for your response. I didnt manage to get this working, with my example. However, it has helped me solve the issue!